# get ip address of datagram spring-integration

Tags: java, spring, udp, spring-integration

I use spring integration for communicate via UDP whit Real Time OS. I want to get back IP address from message.

```
  @Bean
  public MessageChannel udpIn()
  {
    return new DirectChannel();
  }

  @Bean
  public UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter udpInboundAdapter()
  {
    UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter adapter = new UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter(8888);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(udpIn());
    adapter.setListening(true);
    adapter.setPoolSize(7);
    adapter.start();
    return adapter;
  }

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "udpIn")
  public void msgConsumer(Message<byte[]> message)
  {
    System.out.println("Message Received! Payload:" + Arrays.toString(message.getPayload()));
    // HERE I want to get IP address
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UnicastReceivingChannelAdapter` produces a `Message` like:

```
message = getMessageBuilderFactory().withPayload(payload)
                    .setHeader(IpHeaders.HOSTNAME, hostName)
                    .setHeader(IpHeaders.IP_ADDRESS, hostAddress)
                    .setHeader(IpHeaders.PORT, port)
                    .setHeader(IpHeaders.PACKET_ADDRESS, packet.getSocketAddress())
                    .build();
```

Take a looks into those headers in your `msgConsumer()` service method.